# There are 16 students in a class. Can they be paired over 12 time slots such that...

Tags: combinatorics

I came across a scenario in class today that I think makes for an interesting math problem.

There were 16 students in class and each of us was asked to find a partner for a particular hour of the day. For example, I might pair with Janet at 12 p.m., with Armando at 1 p.m., with Kelly at 2 p.m., and so on. I found at the end of the activity that I had one slot left (at 3 p.m., say) but no one else had that slot free. As such, I was unable to complete the assignment. This got me wondering how this generalizes into a problem, which I've stated below.

**Problem**

There are 16 students in a class. Can they be paired (forming groups of 2 students) over 12 time slots such that they meet the following requirements?

- Every student has a partner for each of the 12 time slots.
- No student pairs with the same student twice.

To be clear, it is *not* necessary that every student pairs with every other student, only that no student pairs with another student more than once.

**Proposed Solution**

My suspicion is that as long as there is at least one more student then there are time slots (16 students for 12 time slots, for example), then I think that this should be possible. My reasoning is as follows:

There are 120 ways to form pairs from 16 distinct people ($C_{16,2}$). There are 192 total time slots $(16 \cdot 12 = 192)$. Each time a pair is made, two of these slots are filled. So, we essentially have 96 $(192 \div 2 = 96)$ time slots to fill with 120 potential pairs. So we should have pairings left over, which would mean that the problem should be solvable.

I'm ignoring cases with an odd number of students since that would guarantee that (at least) one person was left out for each time slot.

**Questions**

Is my reasoning sound? Is there a clearer way to think about this? And if this is solvable, why didn't I end up without a partner at 3 p.m.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't exactly say your reasoning is sound, but you are on the right track.  You say that as long as there are more student than there are time slots, it should be possible, but what you've really argued is the reverse; it is impossible if there are not more students than time slots.

A clearer way to think about it may be a round-robin tournament with $2n$ players and $2n-1$ rounds, each consisting of $n$ matches.  In a round-robin, each player plays each of the other competitors exactly once.  If you think of the players as students, the rounds as times slots, and the matches as pairing, you see that the problems are really exactly the same.

It has been known since the $19$th century that a round robin as described above can be scheduled for any even number of players.  See this [scheduling algorithm.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm)

As to your last question, just because a schedule is possible, it doesn't mean that every attempt will succeed.  Indeed, if that were true, there would be no need for an algorithm.

Comment: Can you explain how I've actually argued the opposite? I was trying to say that there are more pairings than slots (once we take into account that my pairing with Janet at 12 p.m. fills hers as well as mine), so we should be able to fill the slots without repeating the pairings.

Comment: And thank you for the note about the round robin tournament scheduling. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: It's not enough to say, "We should be able to do it."  You have to show how to do it.  The reverse is true (and obvious) however; if there are more pairings than slots, it's impossible. There are a lot of these "combinatorial designs" where one can't reject the possibility simply with counting arguments, but constructing the design turns out to be impossible.

Comment: I see. I'm not actually trying to determine whether we can form every pairing in the given number of slots (which as you say, would be impossible), but rather that we can occupy every slot with the given pairings available (even if I never end up pairing with a Roger, Simone, or Elsie, for example).

Comment: The fact that I ended up without a pairing for that time slot had me wondering whether or not it was always possible, hence my question here.

Comment: Well, you just got unlucky. Everyone you had not partnered with at some other time had already scheduled $3$ pm before you got around to scheduling that slot.  Let's say you pair with Janet at $12$ pm.  Meanwhile, the other $14$ students break up into $7$ pairs and schedule the $1$ pm time slot. Neither you nor Janet can schedule the $1$ pm slot, even though very little scheduling has been done at this point.

Comment: That makes sense. Part of my hang up with this was differentiating between possible and guaranteed. Your answer and comments have done just that.